# Why is it so important to avoid infection of lacerations to the scalp?

Tags: medicine, neuroanatomy, infection

There is supposedly something unique with regards to infections of the scalp, although I cannot remember, perhaps it was to do with the CSF and its build up? I have scoured the internet for hours but have not found an answer.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for SE Medical Sciences or whatever it is called.

Comment: No, there is noting unique to scalp lacerations (I've repaired literally hundreds of them) except that they bleed a lot more than the usual laceration. Probably because of that, there's a very low rate of scalp laceration infection. CSF is inside the cranium, not in any contact with the scalp.

Comment: @anongoodnurse i have found an answer to this question. It is to do with deep lacerations of the scalp specifically though.

Comment: The deepest lacerations of the scalp go through the galea and exposes the skull. No lacerations of the skull make contact with the CSF.

Answer (score -1):

Deep lacerations of the scalp that penetrate the fourth layer (area of loose connective tissue) have an increased risk of infection. This is because pus and blood spread easily within it. This can easily pass into the cranial cavity along the emissary veins Therefore, infection can spread from the scalp to the meninges and could lead to meningitis.

Comment: Sources for this?

Comment: This does not sound right to me. Deep lacerations - the deepest go through the galea - are far from uncommon, and while they are less common than the average skull laceration, I've seen and treated very many. I've never seen an infected scalp wound. Again, scalp wounds are less likely to get infected than other wounds due to very high vascularity. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK541038/) While I think this answer is theoretically possible, I assume - as I have never seen it - that it is rare (not that I haven't seen rare things...)

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, but this was answered by my anatomy professor on a worksheet we had to do. Now that you have mentioned the galea, I will email him to ask whether this was a more theoretical question simply for students to see conenction between scalp layers, or if it has clinical relevance, and I'll post an update soon.